# Replace HTML form action with fetch api to webserver

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I managed to store files on my pc using the HTML form action attribute and then handling this request on my Express webserver.
When I now try to replace this with an eventlistener on the submit button of the form instead of using the action attribute to send the post request I can not get it to work.

I get a error message 400 bad request.

#### Fetch

```
let form = document.querySelector('#uploadForm')
let inpFile = document.querySelector('#inpFile')
form.addEventListener('submit', async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('inpFile', inpFile.files[0])
    fetch('http://myip/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
    }).catch(console.error)
})
```

#### HTML

```
<form ref='uploadForm' 
  id='uploadForm' 
  method='post' 
  encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" id="inpFile" />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

#### Express Server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const things = require('./routes/things')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile
    sampleFile.mv(__dirname + '\\files\\' + sampleFile.name, (err) => {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        res.send('File uploaded!')
    })
})
```

Comment: `'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'` you dont have to set this as `fetch()` will do that internally when passing a `FormData` object as the `body` value

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: Also you set the post name to `inpFile` (`append('inpFile'`) but used `sampleFile` (`req.files.sampleFile`) in the server code

Comment: Where is the `change` Event on the `<input type='file' />`? You can't get the file until you get it through the `change` Event.

Comment: I did not know about a change event until you mentioned it now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your html and fetch code your express code should looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const things = require('./routes/things')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

app.use('/upload', fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const { inpFile } = req.files;

    inpFile.mv(path.join(__dirname, 'files', inpFile.name))
      .then(() => res.send('File uploaded!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
})
```

You need to bind middleware to the application:

```
app.use('/upload', fileUpload({
  createParentPath: true
}));
```

And your file object should be in req.files.inpFile.

Also you need to remove headers from your fetch request.